# Woocommerce-If billing phone is already exists check

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have an requirement that billing phone in woocommerce is validate like email. Whenever we want to create an account in woocommerce with same email id, it throws an error email already exists. I want same this feature in billing phone.

Answer (score 2):

this working for me
change wp_usermeta with your table name

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'wooc_extra_register_fields' );

 function wooc_validate_extra_register_fields( $username, $email, $validation_errors ) {

global $wpdb;
$billing_phone =$_POST['billing_phone'];

  if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
         $validation_errors->add( 'billing_first_name_error', __( ' First name is required!', 'woocommerce' ) );
  }
  if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
         $validation_errors->add( 'billing_last_name_error', __( ' Last name is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
  }
 if ( isset($billing_phone ) && empty( $billing_phone ) ) {
         $validation_errors->add( 'billing_phone_error', __( ' Prone is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
  }
$results = $wpdb->get_results('select * from `wp_usermeta` where meta_key = "billing_phone" and meta_value = "'.$billing_phone.'"');
if ( $results ) {
                 $validation_errors->add( 'billing_phone_error', __( 'Phone number already exists..', 'woocommerce' ) );
}
  return $validation_errors;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be your solution :

```
add_filter('woocommerce_new_customer_data', 'risbl_custom_customer_data', 10 );

function risbl_custom_customer_data() {

  global $wpdb;
  $billing_phone = $_POST['billing_phone'];

    $results = $wpdb->get_results('select * from `wp_usermeta` where meta_key = "billing_phone" and meta_value = "'.$billing_phone.'"');
    if ( $results ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Phone number already exists.' ), 'error' );
    }

}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object-it showing this..i have paste your code to theme function.php

Comment: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array..used your updated code

Comment: actually i am using extra register field fname,lname, and phone in registration..now it shows the error phone number already exits but Error: ERROR: Couldn’t register you… please contact us if you continue to have problems.--this also...for freash registration

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function wc_validate_phone_number() {
   $phone = (isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ? trim( 
   $_POST['billing_phone'] ) : '');
   if ( ! preg_match( '/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/',
   $phone ) ) {
      wc_add_notice( __( 'Invalid Phone Number. Please enter with a valid 
      phone number. Eg: (123) 456 7890' ), 'error' );
   }
}
```

Comment: actually I am looking for phone no already exists check not validation of phone no

Answer (score 0):

Code Works Perfect:

```
  add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields',
 'phone', 10 );

  function phone() {

  global $wpdb;
  $billing_phone = $_POST['billing_phone'];

$results = $wpdb->get_results('select * from `wp_usermeta` where meta_key = "billing_phone" and meta_value = "'.$billing_phone.'"');
if ( $results ) {
    wc_add_notice( __( 'Phone number already exists.' ), 'error' );
}

}
```

Comment: This exact answer was posted 5 years ago, complete with the same SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Hook woocommerce_billing_fields will work on  when you place order it will check that also. Php file render from Browser then how will be injected.